# Find first duplicate element in the array given every element smaller than the array size

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

**Input:** [3,4,6,1,3,5,4]

Input is an unsorted array having duplicates. Notice that every element of the array is less than its size 7.

**Output:** 3, which is the first duplicate element.

I can very well use a map, to find out first repeating element, but wondering if there's a better solution as it is mentioned in the problem that all the array elements are smaller than the array.

Can you please help in coming up with an optimal solution for this problem in javascript? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service...or a *"do my homework for me*" service . You are expected to show your attempts to solve whatever problem you have and people here help you fix **your code**

Comment: Thanks for the unsolicited advice. All I was looking is some high level idea to go in the right direction, not the code.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest would probably be something like

```js
var arr = [3,4,6,1,3,5,4];

var first, len=arr.length, i=0;

for (i; i<len; i++) {
 if (arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i]) !== i) {
     first = arr[i];
        break;
    }
}

console.log(first)
```

Shortest to write, something like

```js
var arr = [3,4,6,1,3,5,4];

var first = arr.filter((k,i)=> i!== arr.lastIndexOf(k))[0];

console.log(first)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if there's any solution making use of the condition mentioned in the question that every element is less than the array size.